# Why is my .on("mouseover") event firing on page refresh and not when I 'mouseover' the event

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to Javascript and d3 and trying to get a basic 'mouseover' event to work. The event seems to fire before I actually mouse over the element though which is confusing me.

This is my code:

```
(function (d3) {

const svg = d3.select('svg');

const width = +svg.attr('width');
const height = +svg.attr('height');

const g = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform',`translate(${width/2},${height/2})`);

const circle = g.append('circle')
  .attr('r', 30)
    .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
    .attr('stroke','black');

var data=[1,2,3,4,5,6];

d3.select('circle').on("mouseover", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    svg.selectAll('circle').data(data)
        .enter().append('circle')
            .attr('r', data => data)
            .attr('cx', 20)
            .attr('cy', 20)
}(data));

}(d3));
```

What I'm expecting is for more circles to draw when I mouse over the first circle, however they all draw together as soon as I refresh the page.

As I said I'm a newbie, so any help understanding this would be appreciated. Any contextual background that you could provide/point me towards would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no JavaScript expert but I think you're using a self-invoking function in the event declaration.

try deleting the `(data)` part on the function declaration

```
d3.select('circle').on("mouseover", function(data) {
   console.log(data);
   svg.selectAll('circle').data(data)
       .enter().append('circle')
           .attr('r', data => data)
           .attr('cx', 20)
           .attr('cy', 20)
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work - I get `undefined` for `console.log(data)` and this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: svg.selectAll(...).data(...).enter is not a function
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3play.js:31)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.js:1524)`

Comment: I see, you're trying to use the data variable that you declared your self, when you write, `function(data)` it is telling the program that it will receive a parameter when that event is called since your variable is already accessible within your function, I would try removing the `data` from and only from `function(data)` leaving it just `function()`, let me know if it works

Comment: @Chaz, For reference, the parameter (`data`) provided to the function here: `.on("mouseover", function(data)`, represents the datum of an item in the selection. Since that selection has no bound data, `data` will be undefined in this context. As you just want the variable you declared as `data`, you do not need to specify it as a function parameter (since then `data` will refer to the bound datum (`undefined`) rather than your array).

Comment: As for the self invoking. The function does not need to be self-invoking as the provided function is invoked on the event - you want to pass the function itself to the event handler, not the return value of the function.

Comment: @AndrewReid thank you for that explanation! That makes a lot of sense now - i was stringing together bits of code I had found and trying to get it all to work together, but now I understand what it was doing.